# How to write ー in android keyboard?

Tags: discussion

I don't have ー option in my keyboard so it's really hard for me when trying to type words like this: ハンバーガー、アイスクリーム、ケーキ

Comment: This is a question better-suited for the meta site, but you're talking about the "flick" style Japanese keyboard? You don't have ー next to わ?

Comment: yes my keyboard doesn't have ー so i don't know how to type it

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?